# face detection issue on UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to do a face detecting application for that i have tried one application , i got that reference from one link in that they transform the `UIImageView` and then transform the window. The detection by default works upside down, so as a quick fix they flipping the image and then flipping the window back to make everything look up right again. The image will now be at the bottom of the screen but i need to detect face with out flipping the image and windiw . is it possible? if so please post some code.

Here i have place that code for flipping the image.

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"steves.jpg"]];
[imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
[self.window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height)];
[self.window addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously someone is confused. The face detection provided by CIDetector does *not* require the image to be upside down. More likely the code you're trying to crib from is flipping images for some other reason... Or for no good reason at all, which is surprisingly common.

You can find a simple tutorial example using CIDetector [here](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/).